# Redirecting existing URLs to SEO Friendly URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have came accross a problem that every .htaccess query I've tried wasn't worked out ! I have URLs like this:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?x=product
```

And I want to change it to a user friendly URL like this:

```
http://www.example.com/product/
```

Or it can be:

```
http://www.example.com/product.php
```

I've tried this code below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^x=product$
RewriteRule ^index.php.*$ http://www.example.com/product.php? [R=302,L]
```

Now, it is redirecting perfectly, but this is not the problem. I've used this for only SEO so I must include http://www.example.com/index.php?x=product in the product.php file. Any help can be precious, thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?x=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?x=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will redirect `/index.php?x=product` to `/product/` and will rewrite it internally to `/index.php?x=product` in 2nd rule.

Comment: Thank you very much for this code, it's working as you said but it didn't read any css, javascript vs...it's just hypertext now !

Comment: Only images came to display. I don't know what to do because I really dont understand about rewrite. I put <base href="/" /> to the head of my index.php. Any suggestion would be helpfull !

Comment: You must have the "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" earlier to have the rewrites not done on existing files, like js and css.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put anything in the product.php file. Make sure there is a .htaccess in the directory that has the files you want to make url/seo friendly.

To have it SEO friendly make sure its in this format
`http://www.example.com/product/` not `http://www.example.com/product.php`
if you must have a file extension, have it in `http://www.example.com/products.html` (you want to tell the search engine the page isn't dynamic although it is to get better pagerank)

Insert this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteRule /(.*)/$ products.php?x=$1
```

the `(.*)` pulls the elements out and puts them in variables $1